# Average Calculator for an Array (null arguments returns NaN)

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Uses rest parameter and for...of loop for an array...

```js
function average(...nums) {
    let total = 0;
    for(const num of nums) {
      total += num;
    }
    let avr = total / arguments.length;
    return avr;
}

console.log(average(2, 6));
console.log(average(2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 10));
console.log(average(7, 1432, 12, 13, 100));
// returns NaN - required to return 0. 
console.log(average());
```

Problem: for no arguments - `console.log(average());` - Returns NaN where the correct answer must be 0.

Any good shorthand solution here?

Comment: Add a simple check into the first line of your function `if (!arguments.length) return 0`.

Comment: Or `if (nums.length === 0) return 0;` and use `nums.length` instead of `arguments.length` when calculating the average. Might as well use the rest parameter for what it's worth, right?

Comment: Maybe also make sure `num` is an actual number before adding it to total `if(!isNaN(num) { total += num; }`

Comment: @norbitrial Thank you kindly. Brilliant solution my code is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify the function as -

```
function average(...nums) {
    if(nums.length === 0){
        return 0;
    }
    let total = 0;
    for(const num of nums) {
        total += num;
    }
    let avr = total / arguments.length;
    return avr;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just check arguments.length at the start of the function. Something like:

```
function average(...nums) {
    //check if no args are passed & return 0
    if(arguments.length === 0) return 0;
    //else
    let total = 0;
    for(const num of nums) {
    total += num;
    }
    let avr = total / arguments.length;
    return avr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very elegant but...

```js
const average = (...arr) => arr.reduce( ( acc, current ) => acc + current, 0 ) / (arr.length || 1) ;

console.log(average(2, 6));
console.log(average(2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 10));
console.log(average(7, 1432, 12, 13, 100));
console.log(average());
```